JetBrains syntax highlight for jsRender/jsViews?
My favorite IDE is phpstorm from JetBrains but it seems there is no any plugin for syntax highlight for jsRender/jsViews.
I have found only this support thread on JetBrains:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1245/JSRender-support
But it's not addressed still and there is no solution still.

As far as syntax highlighting within tags {{...}} and data-link="..." I don't see that as plausible (or at least worth the effort to build an extension) as the syntax is unique and can be quite complex.
However, a bigger issue is when using script tags as templates where <script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender"> does not provide HTML syntax highlighting mixed with JsRender/JsViews code; while <script id="tmpl" type="text/html"> does.
Using type="text/html" is fine; it simply tells the browser that it is not javascript that needs to be run and simply ignores it.
This is my experience in VS Code.
